# Can file type affect download or upload speed?

Tags: file, download

For example if we have created from the console with 5 gb size with nothing in it (all 0's in binary) versus a real file, do the protocols compress the data to optimize for speed while transferring?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the download or upload speed only depends on the number of bytes, so the type file is not important

Comment: Are you sure though?